# get clicked(active) DRUPAL menu in page

Tags: drupal

I have in my drupal site the primary links displayer at the top.
I would like to have a block in my internal pages a block witch dsplay the clicked menu ant its child .

May someone help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [menu_get_active_trail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_active_trail/6) to retrieve the active menu item